# Black screen after boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, boot-repair

I recently changed from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, but when I try to boot after installing Ubuntu I only see a white flash and then a black screen. I'm not running Dual Boot, I did a clean install.

My specs are the following:
Intel Core I5 4670k
Motherboard Gigabyte Z87X-UD3H
MSI GTX 750TI
8GB RAM Kingston Hyperx Fury

Before putting the encryption password this appears:

Ivmetad is not active yet,  using direct activation during sysinit
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg

I re-installed 3 times to check if it was an error but I keep getting this black screen

If you could help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sha of the the downloaded iso.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)